# Reducing the journey time of a Hohmann Transfer

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, orbital-motion, space

As part of my investigation into whether Hohmann Transfer Orbit could become more feasible for long term space travel, I was wondering if it would be possible to reduce the journey time to another planet (half the period) by increasing delta-v beyond the required value for the transfer.

If so, is there way to calculate this change in journey time?

Comment: Of course you can (if you have lots delta-v you can do anything), though that wouldn't be Hohmann transfer anymore =)

Comment: It is a very complex thing, the general answer is yes, but likely no one could answer it in a short form.

Answer (score 1):

As I've noted in the comment, the transfer you are considering wouldn't be Hohmann anymore... by definition of the Hohmann transfer. Of course you can go faster. In the most extreme case if your available $\Delta v$ is much greater that orbital velocities you can forget about orbital mechanics altogether and calculate everything as if you considered elementary school problem about train going from $A$ to $B$.

The problem can be stated in the following. We know that at $t_0$ the rocket is at distance $r_1$ from the Sun and has velocity $\vec{v}$ (which is given as a sum of the planet orbital velocity $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{\Delta v}$) At what time $t_1$ it will be at distance $r_2$? We will assume that the rocket will move on the elliptic Keplerian orbit without taking into account all the disturbances.

Luckily (unlike the inverse problem of finding the position knowing time) that can be done analytically but requires a bit of work.

- First, from $r_1$ and $\vec{v}$ you need to calculate basic orbital parameters that remain constant. Those specific energy $\varepsilon$, specific angular momentum $h$, period $T$ semimajor axis $a$ and eccentricity. First two are rather obvious I hope, the latter three can be found by,
  \begin{equation}
  a=-\frac{\mu}{2\varepsilon},\quad e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2\varepsilon h^2}{\mu^2}},\quad T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}}
  \end{equation}
  where $\mu$ is the Sun's standard gravitational parameter.
- Next, you should calculate the **true anomaly** $\nu$ (i.e. angle between current radius vector and radius vector of the perihelion) for the starting and ending points. It can be done if you note that,
  \begin{equation}
  r=a \frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos\nu}
  \end{equation}
- Then you should convert then true anomalies into **eccentric anomalies** $E$ using,
  \begin{equation}
  \tan\frac{E}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-e}{1+e}}\tan\frac{\nu}{2}
  \end{equation}
  Which you then use to calculate **mean anomalies** $M$,
  \begin{equation}
  M=E-e\sin{E}
  \end{equation}
  It is at this step where lies the hard part of the inverse problem.
- And then you should look what mean anomaly is. *That's angle the radius vector of the body would have with perihelion if instead of moving on the elliptic orbit it would move on the circular orbit with the same period.* I.e.
  \begin{equation}
  M=\frac{2\pi}{T}(t-t_0)
  \end{equation}
  where $t_0$ is a time when the body crosses the perihelion. But that means that the difference between mean anomalies would give us the time we want!
  \begin{equation}
  t_2-t_1=\frac{T}{2\pi}(M_2-M_1)
  \end{equation}

Of course we assumed that both moments happen during the same half-period. You may make corrections to the case when they don't.

Comment: @Vedant Dear Vedant, those ideas are not mine but of Johannes Kepler. I simply wrote the basic stuff that you should be able to find in the beginning of any textbook on the celestial mechanics though usually with different notation and likely taking into account the solar mass. I wrote my answer with intention that you will look for the terms I mentioned and explore the concepts more. For example you can read and cite lecture L15 in this open MIT course https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/index.htm